# recursive function to calculate (2^k)m=input

Tags: c++, recursion

**update2**: now it works for even numbers but for odd it doesn't work, when m is even it works and when it's odd it doesn't.

```
void find2Factor(int num, int& k, int& m)
{
    if (num % 2 == 1)
        m = num;
    else
        m = num - 1;
    k = 1;
    fin2FactorRec(num, k, m);
}

void fin2FactorRec(int num, int& k, int& m)
{
    if (m*k == num)
    {
        k = powerof2(k);
        return;
    }
    else if (num%m==0)
        fin2FactorRec(num, k *= 2, m);
    else
        fin2FactorRec(num, k, m -= 2);
}

int powerof2(int n)
{
    int count = 1;
    while (n != 2)
    {
        n /= 2;
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

**update1**: edited to following but it get's stuck on the first recursion and won't get to the second one.

```
void find2Factor(int num, int& k, int& m)
{
    k = m = 1;
    fin2FactorRec(num, k, m);
}

void fin2FactorRec(int num, int& k, int& m)
{
    if (k*m == num)
        return;
    if (num == m)
        return;
    else
    {
        find2Factorrec(num, k, m += 2);
        find2Factorrec(num, k *= 2, m);
    }
}
```

I want to write a function `find2Factor` that gets the integers input,k,m and finds for what `m` and `k` input=(2^k)*m while k isn't smaller then 0 (k can be 0)
and m is odd integer.

this is the piece of code I must use without changing:

```
int main() {

    int num, k, m;

    cin >> num;

    find2Factor(num, k, m);

    cout << k << " " << m << endl;
}
```

so this is how I wrote the function `find2Factor`:

```
void find2Factor(int num, int& k, int& m)
{
    k = m = 0;
    if (k*m == num)
        return;
    if (num == m)
        return;
    else
    {
        find2Factor(num, k, m += 2);
        find2Factor(num, k*2, m);
    }
}
```

but it always initializes k and m while I just want them to be initialized at the beginning...

would appreciate your help

Comment: Since the first line in find2Factor() sets k and m to 0, the recursion can never make progress toward a solution.

Comment: @TomBarron so this is exactly my question, how can I solve it? that it would be initialized once, without messing with the main

Comment: What are the sample inputs you are using?

Comment: If `find2Factorrec(num, k, m += 2)` succeeds in finding the values, it will still call `find2Factor(num, k*2, m)` regardless. Is that what you want?

Comment: @NeilKirk no, I mean that for example num=40, I should get k=3, m=5 because (2^k)*m = (2^3)*5 = 8*5 = 40. but when the program runs, it always gets to `find2Factorrec(num, k, m += 2)` and runs to infinite (instead of using the combination of `find2Factorrec(num, k, m += 2)` and `find2Factorrec(num, k *= 2, m)`)

Comment: @user5647490: 

1. The 2nd if checking for exit conditions should use ">=" instead of "==", because you are incrementing m by 2. .You should not call find2Factor twice in a row. I would suggest calling it

Comment: @RichardSt-Cyr please check the second updated I just edited at the question (above).. I narrowed the problem. and changed the recursion

Comment: Please don't edit the question so much as to be meaningless. I reverted to your fifth revision because as it stands, your last revision would have been closed in a heartbeat.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't change main, then you will need a function to set things up, and a recursive function.

Otherwise, initialize m and k in main, before calling find2Factor.

**Edit after comments:**

The second call doesn't work because m and k are already bigger than their limits.

When using recursion, I prefer to pass parameters by value, because it makes it a lot easier to get them back to their previous values when returning from unsuccessful calls. The function signature could look like:

```
bool internalFind2Factor(int num, int k, int k_pow, int m, int& res_k, int& res_m)
```

Where the returned value would indicate success, k_pow would hold 2**k and res_k and res_m would contain the answer when success.

I would also try incrementing increment k and m in distinct code path, and ensure that we stop recursing if one call is successful.

Comment: Using a static variable could be another approach.

Comment: @Richard St-Cyr I followed your suggestion but yet there's problem with the recursion, only the first recursion works, so it doesn't get to the second one

Comment: @TomBarron How would you reset the static variables for the next call?

Comment: You'd use the static variable to detect the first call, set up your starting condition, then set the static to 0 and never do that branch again.